# Obvious counter examle to the Handshaking Lemma

Tags: definition

The [Handshaking Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) is described thusly in Wikipedia:

> In graph theory, a branch of mathematics, the handshaking lemma is the statement that every finite undirected graph has an even number of vertices with odd degree (the number of edges touching the vertex). In more colloquial terms, in a party of people some of whom shake hands, an even number of people must have shaken an odd number of other people's hands.

I am not implying that Wikipedia is a bastion of honesty or good reporting, but for technical subjects it does seem to suffice as a subject introduction. **The colloquial terms does seem to correctly describe the formal definition**. Thus, why is the following *not* a counter example to the Handshaking Lemma:

> Alice, Bob, and Catwoman meet and all shake hands. Thus Alice has shaken 2 peoples hands, as have both Bob and Catwoman. An odd number of people have each shaken an even number of hands.

**Is there a flaw with my counter example, or do I not fully understand the meanings or implications of the lemma?** If the issue is that the lemma does not define `some people` to include `all people`, then I could easily add another person Darkhelmet who shakes nobody's hand.

Comment: What do you understand "odd degree" to mean, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem says that an even number of people must have shaken an odd number of hands, it says nothing about the how many people have shaken an even number of hands. You flipped the condition. Colloquially, a counter example would have to be of the form "an odd number of people have shaken an odd number of hands"

Comment: So an even number of people (zero people) have shaken an odd number of hands?

Comment: Yup, that's it.